# Overlapping sequences

Tags: algorithm, sequence, time-series

There are many sequences of start-end pairs. How to find all the ranges which are contained in all of the sequences? Start and end are integers and they may be far away, so making bit-fields of the sequences and `&`-ing them is not feasible. The ranges (i.e. start-end pairs) on one "row" (i.e. one sequence) do not overlap, if that helps. And there is lower and upper bound for start and end, 32-bits integers would be enough I think (i.e., 0 <= values <= 65535).

Let me draw an example:

```
|----------|       |---------------------|           |----------|
     |----------------------|                      |-------|
                |---------------------|                 |--|
```

The result should be:

```
                   |--------|                           |--|
```

The example above would read, approximately:

```
row1 = (100, 200), (300, 600), (800, 900)
row2 = (140, 450), (780, 860)
row3 = (280, 580), (820, 860)
result = (300, 450), (820, 860)
```

Also, is there any known algorithm for this? I mean, does this problem have a name?

Comment: Your example doesn't match what you are describing. It seems that you want to find the sequence that has the most overlapping sequences.

Comment: i don't understand the end result, can you clarify?

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion, my bad. Is it ok now?

Comment: "a sequence of of start-end pairs" seems confusing. Are these character sequences or you are talking about ranges like time ranges?

Comment: @AudriusMeškauskas: like time ranges.

Comment: @harold: what do you mean by sorted? One "row" can contain multiple (non-overlapping) ranges. And the various "row"...to really, but I could sort them if that helps...? But according to what?

Comment: @EcirHana by starting point, or ending point, that would be equivalent since they're not overlapping within a row anyway. But never mind that, I'll do some more serious thinking and return when I actually have something.

Comment: Can ranges in one sequence overlap?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That should not be to hard assuming the ranges in each sequence do not overlap. In this case it is just a matter of iterating over all points and tracking when you enter or leave a range.

Throw all your points from all your sequences into one list, sort it and remember for each point if it is a start or end point.

```
100 S ---
140 S  |   ---
200 E ---   |
280 S       |  ---
300 S ---   |   |
450 E  |   ---  |
580 E  |       ---
600 E ---
780 S      ---
800 S ---   |
820 S  |    |  ---
860 E  |   ---  |
860 E  |       ---
900 E ---
```

Now you iterate over this list and every time you encounter a start point you increment a counter, every time you encounter an end point you decrement the counter.

```
      0
100 S 1
140 S 2
200 E 1
280 S 2  
300 S 3 <--
450 E 2 <--
580 E 1
600 E 0
780 S 1
800 S 2
820 S 3 <--
860 E 2 <--
860 E 1
900 E 0
```

When the counter is equal to the number of sequences - three in your example - you have found the start of one range and the next point is the end of this range.

Note that it is not even required to build the list explicitly if the ranges in each sequence are sorted by start or can be sorted by start. In this case you can just iterate over all sequences in parallel by keeping a pointers to the current range in each sequence.

Here the whole thing in C# - the class for ranges.

```
internal sealed class Range
{
    private readonly Int32 start = 0;

    private readonly Int32 end = 0;

    public Range(Int32 start, Int32 end)
    {
        this.start = start;
        this.end = end;
    }

    internal Int32 Start
    {
        get { return this.start; }
    }

    internal Int32 End
    {
        get { return this.end; }
    }
}
```

The class for points with a flag to discriminate between start and end points.

```
internal sealed class Point
{
    private readonly Int32 position = 0;

    private readonly Boolean isStartPoint = false;

    public Point(Int32 position, Boolean isStartPoint)
    {
        this.position = position;
        this.isStartPoint = isStartPoint;
    }

    internal Int32 Position
    {
        get { return this.position; }
    }

    internal Boolean IsStartPoint
    {
        get { return this.isStartPoint; }
    }
}
```

And finally the algorithm and test program.

```
internal static class Program
{
    private static void Main()
    {
        var s1 = new List<Range> { new Range(100, 200), new Range(300, 600), new Range(800, 900) };
        var s2 = new List<Range> { new Range(140, 450), new Range(780, 860) };
        var s3 = new List<Range> { new Range(280, 580), new Range(820, 860) };

        var sequences = new List<List<Range>> { s1, s2, s3 };

        var startPoints = sequences.SelectMany(sequence => sequence)
                                   .Select(range => new Point(range.Start, true));

        var endPoints   = sequences.SelectMany(sequence => sequence)
                                   .Select(range =>  new Point(range.End, false));

        var points = startPoints.Concat(endPoints).OrderBy(point => point.Position);

        var counter = 0;

        foreach (var point in points)
        {
            if (point.IsStartPoint)
            {
                counter++;

                if (counter == sequences.Count)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Start {0}", point.Position);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (counter == sequences.Count)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("End   {0}", point.Position);
                    Console.WriteLine();
                }

                counter--;
            }
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

The output is as desired the following.

```
Start 300
End   450

Start 820
End   860
```

Comment: Elegant, and linear runtime (in total number of intervals) with the right structure.

Comment: It is only `O(n)` if the sequences are already sorted, otherwise sorting the points will obviously make it `O(n log n)`.

Comment: Actually, my idea of a linear implementation for the sorted case was not linear but O(NxM) - M number of sequences, but it may be done in O(N log M).

Comment: Well, this is totally out-of-the-box thinking for me, thanks a lot! Do you have any idea how it might perform vs the approach by @Khaur? I guess it depends a lot on underlying data...

Comment: Khaur's solution is slower from a theoretical viewpoint. It is probably possible to implement the merge step more efficient than with the given pseudo code but I am quite sure that it is not possible to obtain the same running time as my solution. From a practical viewpoint there is probably no relevant performance difference as long as you have to deal only with a few ten or a few hundred ranges.

Comment: Please, one more question. If the sequences were already sorted how would I form 'points' in linear-time? In other words, if I have 10 sequences already sorted how to concatenate them into one array also sorted? I know this is used in merge-sort but there are only 2 sequnces. Do you mean to check all 10 sequences every time for lowest element or is there different trick?

Comment: @EcirHana Linear time is not possible (I was wrong on my first comment), otherwise you could get O(N) regular sort. As I mentioned, you can have O(N log M) building of `points` with [this algorithm](http://inder-gnu.blogspot.fr/2008/01/merge-k-sorted-lists-of-size-n.html)

Comment: I was wrong about that - you can not do it in linear time. At each step you have to look at the current range in each sequence to decide which point to add next. Given 1000 ranges in 10 sequences with 100 ranges each you will have to look at the 10 current ranges 2000 times (2000 points from 1000 ranges with start and end each). So this is `O(mn)` (`m` the number of sequences, `n` the total number of ranges in all sequences) and will be close to linear if the number of sequences is small. Maybe it is possible to speed this up but ad hoc I have no idea or algorithm in mind.

Comment: By the way, nothing prevents to use the same principle as the one I cited in the last comment in my algorithm, making it O(N log M). I'll edit my answer.

Comment: I assumed that there is a faster n-way merging algorithm but was to lazy to look for it.

Answer (score 5):

I think you can do that rather simply by fusing the sequences 2 by 2.

Each fusion should be doable in linear time of the number of intervals in the considered sequences (if the sequences are sorted), and M-1 fusions are required (with M number of sequences)

Taking your example and adding an extra sequence:

```
|----------|       |---------------------|           |----------|
     |----------------------|                      |-------|
                |---------------------|                 |--|
        |-----------------------------------|           |-----|
```

Fuse by pair of sequences:

```
     |-----|       |--------|                        |-----|
                |---------------------|                 |--|
```

Fuse again:

```
                   |--------|                           |--|
```

But you may be able to find a faster way to do it. The worst case has O(N log M) runtime (N total number of intervals).

Edit: Pseudocode for fusion

```
Take s1 and s2 an iterator on each sequence
While there are still intervals in both sequences
    Compare the intervals:
    If s1.begin < s2.begin
        If s2.begin < s1.end
            If s2.end > s1.end
                Add [s2.begin,s1.end] to the fused sequence
                Increment s1
            Else
                Add [s2.begin,s2.end] to the fused sequence
                Increment s2
        Else
            Increment s1
    Else
        Same thing with s1 and s2 reversed
```

Comment: I doubt there is a faster way to do it.. +1

Comment: You lost me there. What do mean by "fuse"? It makes sense looking at your diagrams, but how do you implement a fuse progrmatically?

Comment: Using the fact that both lists are sorted, you can increment an iterator on either the first or the second list of intervals at every step. I'll edit the answer to make it more obvious.

Comment: Looks good but it's not linear time algorithm. More precisely - it has quadratic worst case. Consider a case when the "fusings" don't eliminate any intervals. But still, I might get lucky, I have to think about it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's called the [longest common substring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem#Suffix_tree). I can be solved using suffix trees. There is a pretty clean Java implementation of it available on this [blog](http://illya-keeplearning.blogspot.com/2009/06/suffix-trees-longest-common-substring.html) and it works with more than just two source strings.

I don't know if you are dealing with characters but I'm sure you can probably adapt it if you don't.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood, but I don't want just the longest common range, I would like to get all of them..?

Comment: You do realize that these are *intervals* - the graphical representation is just for helping us visualize it. longest common substring might "catch" blanks

Comment: I see. Then, I don't think LCS helps here because I don't want to create "sentences" out of the ranges, see the bit-field note above.